# Clickable grid with each <td> changing colors using onclick method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm just learning how to make a clickable grid using Jquery and I have difficulty in finding how to make each  block to change colors on click. I was attempting to add a class to each  through the addClass method. My main difficulty is to find each  to incorporate an onclick or changeColor method.

```js
$('body').on('click', 'td', changeColor());

function generateGrid(rows, cols) {
  var grid = "<table>";
  for (row = 1; row <= rows; row++) {
    grid += "<tr>";
    for (col = 1; col <= cols; col++) {
      var cell = "<td> </td>";
      grid += cell;
    }
    grid += "</tr>";
  }
  $("#tableContainer").empty();
  $("#tableContainer").append(grid);
  return grid;
}

function changeColor() {

  this.addClass("clicked");
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

#tableContainer {
  display: table;
  padding: 1px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: .5px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  display: table-cell;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

td:hover {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

.clicked {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="a3.css">
<script src="a3.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
  <!-- <input type = "button" id="bClick" onclick="myFunction()"> -->


  Rows: <input type="number" name="Rows" id="Rows"><br> Columns: <input type="number" name="Columns" id="Columns"><br> Mines: <input type="number" name="mines"> <br><br>

  <button onclick="generateGrid(document.getElementById('Rows').value, document.getElementById('Columns').value)"> Click for Grid </button>


  <div id="tableContainer"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `$('body').on('click', 'td', changeColor());` <-- remove the `()` on changeColor.  You do not want to execute it there.  You want to give it to the `on()` as a callback

Comment: `this.addClass("clicked");` `addClass()` is a jQuery method.  `this` will not be a jQuery object.  You'll need to change it to `$(this).addClass("clicked");` or use `this.classList.add('clicked')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are executing the function you're passing as the event handler argument so remove the `()`.

```
$(document.body).on('click', 'td', changeColor);
```

Then you will be able to use `this` in the handler.

```
function changeColor() {
  const $this = $(this);
  if ($this.hasClass("clicked")) {
    $this.removeClass("clicked")
  } else {
    $this.addClass("clicked");
  }
}
```

```js
$(document.body).on('click', 'td', changeColor);

function generateGrid(rows, cols) {
  var grid = "<table>";
  for (row = 1; row <= rows; row++) {
    grid += "<tr>";
    for (col = 1; col <= cols; col++) {
      var cell = "<td> </td>";
      grid += cell;
    }
    grid += "</tr>";
  }
  $("#tableContainer").empty();
  $("#tableContainer").append(grid);
  return grid;
}

function changeColor() {
  const $this = $(this);
  if ($this.hasClass("clicked")) {
    $this.removeClass("clicked")
  } else {
    $this.addClass("clicked");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

#tableContainer {
  display: table;
  padding: 1px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: .5px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  display: table-cell;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

td:hover {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

.clicked {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="a3.css">
  <script src="a3.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- <input type = "button" id="bClick" onclick="myFunction()"> -->
  Rows: <input type="number" name="Rows" id="Rows"><br> Columns: <input type="number" name="Columns" id="Columns"><br> Mines: <input type="number" name="mines"> <br><br>
  <button onclick="generateGrid(document.getElementById('Rows').value, document.getElementById('Columns').value)"> Click for Grid </button>
  <div id="tableContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Small personal tweak.  If you change `'body'` with `document.body` you can avoid a DOM lookup.

Comment: Noice – got you

Comment: Close, but it would just be `$(document.body)`

Answer (score -1):

Your issue here is that you are binding the `click` event on the `td` before they are ever on the page. You need to make sure to bind the `click` function at the bottom of your `generateGrid()` function, like so:

```js
function generateGrid(rows, cols) {
  var grid = "<table>";
  for (row = 1; row <= rows; row++) {
    grid += "<tr>";
    for (col = 1; col <= cols; col++) {
      var cell = "<td> </td>";
      grid += cell;
    }
    grid += "</tr>";
  }
  $("#tableContainer").empty();
  $("#tableContainer").append(grid);
  $('td').click(function(){
    changeColor($(this));
  });
}
function changeColor(cell) {
  if(cell.hasClass('clicked')){
    cell.removeClass('clicked');
  } else {
  cell.addClass('clicked');
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

#tableContainer {
  display: table;
  padding: 1px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: .5px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  display: table-cell;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

td:hover {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

td.clicked {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="a3.css">
<script src="a3.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
  <!-- <input type = "button" id="bClick" onclick="myFunction()"> -->


  Rows: <input type="number" name="Rows" id="Rows"><br> Columns: <input type="number" name="Columns" id="Columns"><br> Mines: <input type="number" name="mines"> <br><br>

  <button onclick="generateGrid(document.getElementById('Rows').value, document.getElementById('Columns').value)"> Click for Grid </button>


  <div id="tableContainer"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You appear to be unfamiliar with delegate event bindings.  That is what the OP is using and is perfectly valid for this use case.  Ref. http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/